# Google Cloud logging list entries query filter requires a timestamp

Tags: google-cloud-logging

My client code to query Cloud Logging logs returns no results for my query filter unless that filter also includes a timestamp.

The query code:

```
import google.cloud.logging_v2 as gc_logging

client = gc_logging.Client(project=GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID)
result_generator = client.list_entries(
    resource_names=[f"projects/{GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}"],
    filter_=filter,
)
results = []
for result in result_generator:
    results.append(result)
```

Without a timestamp:

```
filter = 'resource.type="ml_job"'
```

No results

With a timestamp:

```
filter = 'resource.type="ml_job" AND timestamp < "2023-10-06T00:00:00.000Z"'
```

All the expected results are found.

Logs are in the `_Default` bucket.